# Labels and references with if statements

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing

Im building a question booklet with answers attached at the back using the exam document type so I'm inputting the .tex file twice, like this:

```
\noprintanswers
\input{paper}
\newpage
\printanswers
\input{paper}
```

I don't want the graphics in questions to print in the solutions so I've been using:

```
\ifprintanswers\else
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}\label{...}
...
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\fi
```

Sometimes it's also necessary to have an alternative figure show in the solutions, in which case I'll have it in the initial part of the if statement.

However, the numbering of my figures is not in the expected order because of this, likely because figures not created because of the if statement are still getting assigned their number. Is there a way to make latex only assign label figure numbers when they are actually drawn so it won't affect the final number ordering?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. While testing, did you do several runs? The labels and stuff are stored in the AUX file and re-read on the next run. This might cause the problem.

Comment: Also, you might want to edit your post in order to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Hi sorry I found the root cause of my question which wasnt what i expected, I think its best I ask a new question with a minimal working example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP found out the problem is another (see their comment).